# Running SQLCMD from bat file loops infinitely

Tags: php, batch-file, sqlcmd

I have the following SQLCMD which connects to a remote database executes a query ands saves it as a csv file.

```
sqlcmd -S tcp:0.0.0.0,1433 -U user -P pass -d mydb -W -w 999 -s "," -Q "SELECT * FROM dbo.CSVData" -o "C:\wamp\sqlcmd.csv"
```

This works fine when i run it manually from command prompt.

I need to run the sqlcmd command from php and i have tried several execution commands in php but none works. The only option is using .bat files and call them through php but when i do so the sqlcmd command runs continuously (for several hundred times) and quits. I have tried using /wait and exit but this makes it worse by opening hundreds and hundreds of command prompt windows and it freezes the system. Below is the code i tried. Please let me know what i am doing wrong. Thanks.

```
@echo off  

echo Running sqlcmd  
start /wait sqlcmd -S tcp:0.0.0.0,1433 -U user -P pass -d mydb -W -w 999 -s "," -Q "SELECT * FROM dbo.CSVData" -o "C:\wamp\sqlcmd.csv"


:exit
```

Comment: Have you tried running the batch file from the cmd prompt?  Just to be sure that PhP  code is not looping?  I do not see how the batch file you list could cause a loop.

Comment: Write `start "" /wait ...` (`start` may interprete the first quoted string it encounters as a window title, so giving an empty string `""` explicitly defines one and avoids problems with broken up command lines)...

Comment: I am not running the .bat file from PHP. I am just running by double clicking it @Joe C

Answer (score 1):

I found what the issue was. I named the .bat file as sqlcmd.bat and that caused the program to run infinitely. I renamed the .bat file and it is working perfectly. A stupid mistake. My bad.

Comment: I did the exact same thing...LOL.  Thanks for posting!